# WiFi Network showing twice in my Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, certificate

I installed Network Certificate of a company in my laptop having Windows 10 OS, which means whenever am in range of company WiFi then my laptop should auto-connect to WiFi and it does perfectly.

My question is about the "WiFi SSID showing twice with a number 2 at side". Please see the following picture for understanding.

[image]

Thinking the certificate could be duplicated. I typed certmgr.msc in Run but could see only one certificate listed as shown in following pictures.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following command in Command Prompt.

```
netsh wlan delete profile name="xxx" interface="Wi-Fi"

where xxx = duplicated wifi name
```

Comment: Adding my comment here to say this worked for me. In my case, though, I had the same wi-fi network with the same name popping up. So when I ran this it deleted both of them. Wasn't a big deal though, since all I had to do was re-enter the wi-fi password once to get the wi-fi remembered again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to delete the extra Wi-Fi network profile?

1. Click on the `Start` button and select `Settings`
2. Select the `Network & Internet` icon
3. Click on `Wi-Fi` on the upper-left and then select `Manage known networks` on the right

[image: Manage Known Networks]

4. Choose the duplicate network name (the one that isn't connected) and select `Forget`

[image: Forget Wi-Fi Network]

5. Close the `Settings` app accordingly

(Source: [How to Delete a Wireless Network Profile in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3507-wireless-network-profile-delete-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Yes! I tried that too. Even opted out ' connect automatically when within range ' but still it gets connected when I restart my Laptop.

Comment: Interesting.  Have you considered the possibility of forgetting *both* of them, and then adding back just one?

Comment: Forgetting **both** haven't tried. Is there any logic behind? Anyway, will give it a try and let you know. (:

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issues in multiple occasions. I tried deleting the network profile and 'forgetting' the router, only for the same issue to reoccur.

I found the quickest and easiest fix is to open a Personal Hotspot on your mobile phone and connect your laptop to it. Once connected, then 'forget' the router with which you are having the problem. Once done, refresh your desktop page. After that, rejoin your preferred Wi-Fi router. When it reconnects, it will do so to the correct router and not the duplicate.

Sometimes you have to do this process twice, but it works.